# Fredholm Alternative Definition

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, compact-operators, integral-equations

I'm reading Introductory functional analysis by Kreyszig and it discuss Fredholm alternative in the following way:

8.7-1 Definition (Fredholm alternative). A bounded linear operator $A:X \rightarrow X$ on a normed space $X$ is said to satisfy the Fredholm alternative if $A$ is such that either (I) or (II) holds:

- (I) The nonhomogeneous equations $Ax = y, A^\times f = g$ have solutions $x$ and $f$,
  respectively, for every given $y \in X, g \in X'$, the solutions being unique. The corresponding homogeneous equations $Ax = 0, A^\times f = 0$ have only the trivial solution  $x = 0, f = 0$. ($A^\times$ is the adjoint operator of $A$ and $X'$ is the dual space of $X$.)
- (II) The homogeneous equations $Ax= 0, A^\times f = 0$  have the same number of linearly independent solutions $x_1, ..., x_n$ and $f_1, ..., f_n$, $n \geq 1$ resepctively. The nonhomogeneous equations $Ax = y, A^\times f = g$ are not solvable for all y and g, respectively; they have a solution if and only if y and g are such that $f_k(y) = 0, g(x_k) = 0$ for all $k = 1,2,..., n$.

What I'm confused about is on condition (II): Is there a contradiction between "*The nonhomogeneous equations are not solvable for all $y$ and $g$*" and "*they have a solution iff ...*"?

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no contradiction. The equation $Ax=y$ is solvable **if and only if** $f_k(y)=0$ for all $k=1\dots n$.

The statement "The inhomogeneous equations are not solvable for all right-hand sides" is made precise in the second half of that long sentence "they have a solution if and only if...".

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Just want to make sure: Because $f_k(y) = 0, g(x_k) = 0$ would never happen so we claim that $Ax = y$ will never have a solution, is that what you mean?

Comment: No, incorrect. The conditions $f_k(y)=0$ are just finitely many linear equations on $y$ from an infinite-dimensional space. So there are **many** non-zero $y$ fulfilling this side condition.

Comment: That's a little confusing, if $f_k(y) = 0$ is possible for some $y$ then $Ax = y$ should be solvable according to your first statement in the reply. I believe I misunderstood something.